# How to properly solve T(n) = T(n-1) + O(2^n)?

Tags: recurrence-relation

I've been trying to solve this recurrence: **T(n) = T(n-1) + O(2^n)**

My approach when writing everything out and solving the geometric series was: T(n) = O(2^n).

T(n) = c2^n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ...)

= c2^n * (1/2)^i for i from 0 to infinity

T(n) <= d*2^n for some constant d.

Comment: Your question is a very basic one. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599) which cover some fundamentals you seem to be missing in detail. Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific problems you encountered. Good luck!

Comment: Nitpick: you were given not a recurrence, but a whole set of them. Instances include $T(n)  = T(n-1) + 2^n$ (what your teacher probably intended you to solve) but also $T(n) = T(n-1) + 1$ (which has a very different solution!), and everything in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is fine for most purposes. If you want a really rigorous proof without "dot dot dots," then you need to use induction. For that you need to make the constant in big-Oh explicit, and use your "back of the envelope calculation" to come up with the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Yeah, for my purpose I don't have to create a rigorous proof. And as for my answer, do you believe I got it correct (**T(n) = O(2^n)**)? I'm a bit new to solving recurrence relations for time complexity, and just want to make sure I am not neglecting anything huge.

Comment: Yup, you got it right, although I think these kinds of questions are frowned upon here.